# GDB Missing separate debuginfos

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb, fedora

I'm using fedora 20 and trying to use GDB. But I got this error message which prevents me from debugging program.

`Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install nss-softokn-freebl-3.17.4-1.fc20.x86_64`

I ran the command to install as instructed, I've got this message

```
$ sudo debuginfo-install nss-softokn-freebl-3.17.4-1.fc20.x86_64
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
fedora-debuginfo/20/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                         | 3.5 kB  00:00:00     
fedora-source/20/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                            | 3.9 kB  00:00:00     
google-chrome                                                                                                                                                                               |  951 B  00:00:00     
updates/20/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                                  | 1.5 kB  00:00:00     
updates-debuginfo/20/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                        | 3.3 kB  00:00:00     
updates-source/20/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                           | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
updates-testing/20/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                          | 1.6 kB  00:00:00     
updates-testing-debuginfo/20/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                | 3.5 kB  00:00:00     
updates-testing-source/20/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                   | 3.7 kB  00:00:00     
google-chrome/primary                                                                                                                                                                       | 1.8 kB  00:00:00     
google-chrome                                                                                                                                                                                                  3/3
Could not find debuginfo for main pkg: nss-softokn-freebl-3.17.4-1.fc20.x86_64
Package glibc-debuginfo-2.18-19.fc20.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No debuginfo packages available to install
```

After did this I tried again still see the same issue in GDB.
My GDB version is:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora 7.7.1-21.fc20
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fedora 20 is EOL. This means the repositories with provided packages (and debug information) are not be available anymore (or will not be). You should update to supported version (Fedora 22 or 23 ATM).

Also the package version you are trying to install is outdated.

If you really need to install the package for debugging something with this exact version, you can download the package from [koji](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=608257) and install by hand:

```
wget https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/nss-softokn/3.17.4/1.fc20/x86_64/nss-softokn-debuginfo-3.17.4-1.fc20.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install nss-softokn-debuginfo-3.17.4-1.fc20.x86_64.rpm
```

But note, this is really not a recommended to use outdated system, since it is not receiving any security updates.

Comment: trying fedora archive repo maybe useful for some people. [https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/20/Everything/x86_64/debug/n/](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/20/Everything/x86_64/debug/n/)

Comment: @NickDong right. But this particular version is from updates so it is not available in your link either.

Comment: Yes, the debuginfo edition should be same with the library edition. Update the newest library from archive repo [nss-softokn-freebl-3.19.1-1.0.fc20.x86_64.rpm](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/20/x86_64/), and download the newest debuginfo from archive update debug repo. [nss-softokn-debuginfo-3.19.1-1.0.fc20.x86_64.rpm, updates/20/x86_64/debug/](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/20/x86_64/debug/).  The repo folders are various for OS. updates/31/Everything/x86_64/debug/, updates/27/x86_64/debug/, updates/20/x86_64/debug/.